# Replacing PayPal SetExpressCheckout SOAP API with REST API V2

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, express-checkout, paypal-soap

We are in the process of replacing our Paypal SOAP API calls ([SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/nvp-soap-api/merchant/set-express-checkout-soap/?mark=SetExpressCheckout?mark=setexpresscheckou) etc.) with the Paypal REST API V2. 
Three questions:

1) Paypal has two similar APIs: [orders](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/) and [payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v2/). Which one is considered to be the replacement for [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/nvp-soap-api/merchant/set-express-checkout-soap/?mark=SetExpressCheckout?mark=setexpresscheckou)?

2) We use the tokens returned by [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/nvp-soap-api/merchant/set-express-checkout-soap/?mark=SetExpressCheckout?mark=setexpresscheckou) to do a capture or refund later. Can the tokens we got from [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/nvp-soap-api/merchant/set-express-checkout-soap/?mark=SetExpressCheckout?mark=setexpresscheckou) also be used to do a capture / refund using the REST APIs? (If not, we cannot do a "big-bang" migration, but keep both implementations in place until we are sure no capture or refund will take place for transactions which have been issued with the SOAP API).

3) Does the merchant need to amend anything in his profile, e.g. give new rights to use the REST API? For example, we use SOAP API call [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/nvp-soap-api/merchant/transaction-search-soap/?mark=TransactionSearch), which requires special rights - are those also valid for REST API calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Creating a v2/order replaces SetExpressCheckout. Capturing a v2/order replaces DoExpressCheckoutPayment.  The capture will return a new transaction id that is a v2/payment object, and this v2/payment object id is the only thing that is preserved in www.paypal.com for accounting purposes (the v2/order id is not used for accounting; like an EC token, it is for the payment approval process only)

For the front-end, use
    https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

[ You mentioned capturing later, so the following won't apply to that particular case, but: *if* your flow were set up to capture right after approval with the buyer present, then -- once everything about your implementation is working for the happy path -- don't neglect to add support for [handling funding source failures](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integration-features/funding-failure/), so that if the immediate capture fails due to e.g. the buyer's first card being declined, this is propagated back to the UI and the buyer can select a different funding source right away ]

2) SetEC tokens cannot be mixed with REST APIs for capture

3) Yes and no. If you're using a REST API to search transactions, then what will matter are the permissions of the REST ClientID+Secret you are using. What will be most straightforward will be for the merchant to generate a new REST app in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications with all the necessary permissions, and provide you with that REST App's live ClientID+Secret.